# Iterate function across columns in data.frame

Tags: r, apply

I want to apply some function from a package in R to every column in one data.frame. As for this function, the data must be structured like the following data.frame called x:

```
          var1   group

sample1   100     1
sample2   200     1
sample3   300     1
sample4   150     2
sample5   200     2
sample6   100     2
```

Using the function on just one column, I must write:

```
foo <- random.function(x$var1, x$group)
```

But what I have is a data.frame with many variables (var1,var2,var3,var4...) and want to apply this function to each column independently.

I have tried the following:

```
foo2 <- apply(x, 2, function(x) random.function(x, group))
```

But I get an error saying that variables are not numeric.

I think the problem deals with asigning a name to the x and group inside the random.function call for apply.

Do you know how could I solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: [`lapply`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.3/topics/lapply), as in `lapply(x, random.function, x$group)`.

Comment: If you always want to use the same `x$group` column in your function, you should put `x$group` in your apply function instead of `group`

Comment: You might also be having a problem because this applies the function to *every* column, even some that are type `character` or `factor`, which might give you errors depending on what `random.function` is.

Comment: Re: using apply for columns  tha tare of mixed classes;  even if it doesn't give you an overt red letter error, it will probably give you junk. The `apply fucntion should only be used on matrices and section of dataframes that can reasonable be turned into matrices. The `lapply` function is what you should be using, and you should be using named formal parameters as well.